# Pseudoinverse of large sparse matrix in R

Tags: r, sparse-matrix, svd, matrix-inverse

I am trying to calculate the pseudoinverse of a large sparse matrix in R using the singular value decomposition. The matrix L is roughly 240,000 x 240,000, and I have it stored as type dgCMatrix. $L$ represents the Laplacian of a large diameter graph, and I happen to know that the pseudoinverse $L^+$ should also be sparse. From empirical observations of a smaller subset of this graph, L is ~.07% sparse, while $L^+$ which is ~2.5% sparse.

I have tried using pinv, ginv, and other standard pseudoinverse functions, but they error out due to memory constraints. I then tried to opt for the sparse matrix svd provided by the package irlba, which I was then going to use to compute the pseudoinverse using the standard formula after converting all outputs to sparse matrices. My code is here:

```
lim = 40
digits = 4
SVD =irlba(L,lim)
tU = round(SVD$u,digits)
nonZeroU = which(abs(U)>0,arr.ind = T)
sparseU = sparseMatrix(i=nonZeroU[,2],j=nonZeroU[,1],x = U[nonZeroU])
V = round(SVD$v,digits)
nonZeroV = which(abs(V)>0,arr.ind = T)
sparseV = sparseMatrix(i=nonZeroV[,1],j=nonZeroV[,2],x = U[nonZeroV])
D = as(Diagonal(x=1/SVD$d),"sparseMatrx")
pL =D%*%sparseU
pL = sparseV%*%pL
```

I am able to get to the last line without an issue, but then I get an error due to memory constraints that says

```
Error in sparseV %*% pL : 
  Cholmod error 'problem too large' at file ../Core/cholmod_dense.c, line 105
```

Of course I could piece together the pseudoinverse entry by entry using a for loop and vector multiplications, but I would like to be able to calculate it using a simple function that takes advantage of the sparsity of the resultant pseudoinverse matrix. Is there any way to use the SVD of L to efficiently and approximately compute the pseudoinverse of $L+$, other than calculating each row individually?

Comment: have you tried RcppEigen or RcppArmadillo? (I haven't worked with sparse matrices in R, so I don't know for sure that it can help). It might be easier to work with larger-than-in-memory data in these frameworks.

Comment: Yes, I am using rARPACK to do sparse matrix computations, which depends on RcppEigen and RSpectra. Very helpful, but not enough to get the pseudoinverse